# Does recursion alter the way .shift() and .slice() remove elements from arrays?

Tags: javascript, recursion

It took me a while but I finally got a working version of a code to determine if an array contained elements that, when summed up in the proper combination, could equate to its largest element.

My question though is why one of my earlier attempts (which used the .shift() method instead of the .slice() one, shown in comments below) fails whenever run in this recursive function.

When I try these two combinations separately they seem to work just the same. Any ideas?

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 

  arr.sort(function(a,b){
   return a - b;
  });
  var largest = arr.pop();

  function find(array, target){
     if(array.length === 0){
       return target === 0; 
     } else {

       //working attempt with slice
       var element = array[0];
       var newArray = array.slice(1);

       //first attempt with shift
       //var newArray = array;
       //var element = newArray.shift(); 

       var newTarget = target - element;
       return find(newArray, target) || find(newArray, newTarget);
     }
  }
  return find(arr, largest);   
}

//test
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([3,5,-1,8,12]));
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice()` returns a copy, `Array.prototype.shift` modifies an array in-place. Iterating over an array that is being modified almost always leads to issues.

Comment: Post your earlier attempt (with `.shift` usage) as well

Comment: `var newArray = array;` --- this does not create a new array, it creates a new reference to the same array.

Comment: Ah darn, thanks for pointing that out. If I were to cut out the 'newArray' variable entirely then, is it possible to feed the recursive call to 'find' a shifted version of the original array? or is it necessary to use a copy instead, as was the case with slice